# Two different syntax for Ruby Mechanize.get(url) - what is the benefit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

What is the difference between those syntax?
Is there any benefit with the first over the second?

```
agent = Mechanize.new

# first
agent.get(url) do |page|
work
end

#second
page = agent.get(url)
```

Which one should I use when and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways of calling the get method end up doing the same thing. You can use it either way you like. The first way where it allows you to pass a block might be useful in writing more concise and/or readable code. Its up to you to choose whichever fits your need. Take for example;

```
agent = Mechanize.new

agent.get(url) do |page|
   item = page.forms.first do |form|
     form.fieldname = "foo"
   end.submit
   # do something with item
end
```

which reads better than

```
page = agent.get(url)
form = page.forms.first
form.fieldname = "foo"
item = agent.submit(form).body
#do something with item
```

Same case applies when doing Mechanize initialization. I prefer

```
@agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
  agent.redirect_ok = true
}
```

to

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
@agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
@agent.redirect_ok = true
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of preference, pick whatever style you find the better to use and read. One advantage of the first is that you don't have to make any assignment, but it's not really important (unless your code is in a view, where you should avoid assignment - but this is another topic)